# Is nodejs + redis reliable?

Tags: node.js, redis

Seems there has been some data loss with nodejs + redis :

https://hallard.me/damaged-community-forum-lost-data/
https://community.nodebb.org/topic/6904/how-to-export-from-redis-to-mongodb-my-database-got-wiped/58

Did someone experience the same disaster and know how to fix it apart from backuping up the whole stuff.

Answer (score 1):

At the company i work at, we've been using it for quite a long time now and it never failed us.

In my opinion, you should never use a database you are not very familiar with, then and **only then** you will face problems such as saving corrupted data or `"losing data"`.

redis will lose all its data in case of crashes (if the server memory maxes out for example) hence you will need to use redis persistence modules.

there are two types of redis persistence data modules, RDB and AOF. you should choose consciously choose which one (or both) to use based on the nature of data you're going to store in there.

- The RDB persistence performs point-in-time snapshots of your dataset at specified intervals.
- the AOF persistence logs every write operation received by the server, that will be played again at server startup, reconstructing the original dataset. Commands are logged using the same format as the Redis protocol itself, in an append-only fashion. Redis is able to rewrite the log on background when it gets too big.

read more about it here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

here is a quote from a good blog post about using redis as a primary database:

> Redis persistence is not less reliable compared to other databases, it
>   is actually more reliable in most of the cases because Redis writes in
>   an append-only mode, so there are no crashed tables, no strange
>   corruptions possible.

source: https://blog.andyet.com/2012/02/09/redis-reliability-for-realtime-apps/

node should not affect how redis work, its only used to communicate data from and to redis, you should not worry about using `node` in particular.